# How to get STRING response from RestTemplate postForLocation?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm creating a REST Client in Java with RestTemplate from Spring Framework.

Everything is fine until i have to do a post with **postForLocation**.

The webservice i'm having access return a json with informations about the POST ACTION.

In PHP it's fine but i really don't understand how to do in Java with RestTemplate.

```
public String doLogin()
    {
        Map<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();

        args.put("email", AUTH_USER);
        args.put("token", AUTH_PASS);

        String result = restTemplate.postForLocation(API_URL + "account/authenticate/?email={email}&token={token}", String.class, args);

        return result;
    }
```

This returns NULL.

With same code but using **getForObject** (and of course, changing the URL to something right) I have a full response, i.e. this works:

`String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);`

So... how get the RESPONSE from a **postForLocation**?

Obs.: Sorry if this question is dumb. I'm beginner in Java

Comment: You should post the "answer" as an answer.

Comment: Thanks... first time i need to do that :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to one of answers i've figured out how get the response from a POST with Spring by using the postForObject

```
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "account/authenticate/?email="+ AUTH_USER +"&token="+ AUTH_PASS, null, String.class);
```

For some reason i can't use arguments with MAP and have to put them inline in URL. But that's fine for me.

Comment: i get a string array as a response, How do i get this Alex ?

Comment: Hi @Antony, sorry for the late response. Actually I've received a String Array as response too. In this question I think you can figure out how I made:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656938/parsing-json-string-as-simple-as-possible-with-gson

Comment: i have done that, i was confused with the out put, it is PHP serialized string and i have to convert to Java using php serializer. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The `postForLocation` method returns the value for the Location header. You should use `postForObject` with the `String` class, which returns the server's response.

So like this:

```
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "account/authenticate/?email={email}&token={token}", String.class, args);
```

This will return the response as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Even so, your code seens to be wrong (here got a error message), but i've figured out now and edited my question with the answer. Thanks!