# Parsing JSON String as simple as possible with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Using GSON, how can i return a single key from a Multidimensional Json String?

Here is the Multidimensional Json String:

```
{"statusCode":0,"statusDescription":"OK","data":{"user":{"id":xxx,"company_id":xxx,"account_type":"5","enable_locations":true,"intuit_user_id":null,"nick_name":"xxx","is_owner":"1","enabled":"1"},"session_token":"xxx"}}
```

I want to return the "session_token" key value.

I'm trying this:

```
class app {
    static class Response {
        String session_token;
    }
    public void getSessionToken() {

        String x = {"statusCode":0,"statusDescription":"OK","data":{"user":{"id":xxx,"company_id":xxx,"account_type":"5","enable_locations":true,"intuit_user_id":null,"nick_name":"xxx","is_owner":"1","enabled":"1"},"session_token":"xxx"}}
        Response r = new Gson().fromJson(x, Response.class);
        System.out.println(r.session_token);
    }
}
```

But with this, my **r.session_token** returns null.

Comment: huh?  So you are manually creating a JSON string on the server side and trying to get the value by supplying the key?

Comment: @wirey No.... i just made the example. I'm retrieving the JSON String from a webserver and i need to parse it. But i need ONLY a single key, nothing else.

Comment: @wirey, what? getParameter are not only for GET and POST parameters? How getParameter will help me to get a string that is on page (retrieved from webserver)? The string is like this: `http://setster.com/api/v2/company/6877/service`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use Gson's `JsonParser` class directly and extract the data from the parse tree:

```
String myJsonString = "{\"name\":\"john\",\"lastname\":\"smith\"}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(myJsonString); 
JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
String lastName = jsonObject.get("lastname").getAsString();
System.out.println(lastName);
```

That said, it's debatable whether this would save you any real time over:

(edited from comments below):

```
class App {

    static class Response {
        String lastname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myJsonString = "{\"name\":\"john\",\"lastname\":\"smith\"}";
        Response r = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString, Response.class);
        System.out.println(r.lastname);
    }
}
```

Gson will silently ignore the fact that there's more data in the JSON than you're interested in, and later on you *might* be interested in it, in which case it's trivial to add fields to your `Response` class.

**Edit due to question changing:**

You have a JSON object. It contains a field `data` whose value is an object. Inside *that* object you have a field `session_token` that you're interested in.

Either you have to navigate to that field through the parse tree, or you have to create Java classes that all will map to. The Java classes would resemble (at the bare minimum):

```
class Response {
    Data data;
}

class Data {
    String session_token;
}
```

Comment: How retrieve the **lastname key**? **r.lastname**? I've tried but it returns *null*.

Comment: See edit. Note your field names in your Java class and the field names in your JSON must match including case unless you annotate your Java class fields with `@SerializedName` to map them to something else. In a real application you'd have a getter in the `Response` class that returned the value.

Comment: I think it is because my JSON string are multidimensional. I will edit my question with this.

Comment: Well, whatever your *real* JSON is, you either have to traverse the parse tree to get to what you want, or create a Java class that maps to your JSON correctly.