# Gson covert to and from only part of Json to kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson, transformation

I have an input json payload:

```
{
  "header": null,
  "body": {
    "a": "1,2,3,4,5",
    "c": "d",
    "id": 23.5,
    "number": 123
  }
}
```

and my program needs to convert it to the following output payload:

```
{
  "header": null,
  "body": {
    "a": [{"a":"1"},{"a":"2"},{"a":"3"},{"a":"4"},{"a":"5"},],
    "c": "d",
    "id": 23.5,
    "id2": 23.5,
    "number": 123
  }
}
```

Header is always null in both input and output. I have created a class for input and output body:

```
data class InBody (
    val a: String,
    val c: String,
    val id: Double,
    val number: Long
)
data class OutBody (
    val a: List<AIndividual>,
    val c: String,
    val id: Double,
    val id2: Double,
    val number: Long
)
data class AIndividual(val a: String)
```

As you can see the transformation between both input required is minimal.

1. Need to split `a` into a list of objects
2. need to duplicate the `id` field to `id2` in output

I am thinking to use Gson to convert the json to input model class to the output model class then output json.. Is there an easier way to do this instead??

Also if I go according to this solution, how to use Gson to only read the `body` element of the `json` into the `InBody` class (and ignore header) and same when convert `OutBody` class to `json`??

If Gson is not a suitable library for this and any other approach is better, please let me know..

Comment: Gson is not great when working with Kotlin in general. It uses unsafe field reflection that might mess up your types (especially nullability). I would strongly recommend Kotlin-first libraries instead like Kotlinx Serialization, or if you must Jackson with the Kotlin module.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a concern (rarely is) a would do the whole transformation back and forth.
To me is not worth the trouble to start doing things manually, is error prone and when a new change comes up you have to keep doing unsafe code that needs thorough tests.

Comment: what you were first thinking, json to InBody with Gson, InBody to OutBody with your mapper/code, OutBody to json with Gson

Comment: Yes that it is right but it seems like alot of code for a trivial transformation... And using Gson makes it more ugly.. do you have any better solutions?

Comment: No, sorry this is not what you want to hear, what I mean is the simpler solution is better for me. You can probably transform to JSONObject and operate on that level. But as I said, I think is less code but takes more time to get right, and you lose the certainty of the proven tool. So I think that is probably better to just do the transformation in and out.

Comment: You mean get rid of the data classes and gson library?? Just do the transformation on the string json??

Comment: I try not to do this as much as possible, but I mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16657114/687938

Comment: Not sure I understand what u are saying. or how that answer relates to my question.... Sorry i am new to this . can you please explain using an example if u are able to?