# Springboot handler errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I using the springboot resttemplate to call some REST services, but some service quem return the 404 error, returns a text message with the list of errors (after process my data)

How can I catch thats error and transform into a object in my app?

I using this sample to create a errorHandler, but don`t know how transform

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

tks

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the response into a string like below.

`postForLocation` method returns the value for the Location header. You should use `postForObject`, which returns the server's response.

So like this:

```
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "account/authenticate/?email={email}&token={token}", String.class, args);
```

Here `args` is `Map<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();` to put arguments for the API.

Refer : [postForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForLocation-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-)
and [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669337/how-to-get-string-response-from-resttemplate-postforlocation)